# jquery pop up(php inside) when browser idle

Tags: php, jquery

good day everyone,
i have a little question about jquery, is it possible if we want to make jquery pop up which it contains a php and mysql data when the browser idle(about 30 min) :D

Someone can give me an example or any tutorial, will help? thx

Comment: What have you tried?  Easy way, set a timer function, after a certain time has passed, do actions.

Comment: yes, you can simply use jquery $(selector).load(url) and then popup...

Comment: Use AJAX to get data from mysql via PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you started:

```
var remindTimer;
function remind() {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/getData.php',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
function restartRemindTimer() {
    clearTimeout(remindTimer);
    remindTimer = setTimeout(remind, 1800000); // 30 min
}
$(document).on('mousemove keypress', restartRemindTimer);
```

Comment: Except that 30min idle probably won't involve mouse movement....

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer.  You are right.

Comment: nothing happen.. can you giving example more spesific e.e

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
//Increment the idle time counter every minute.
var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000); // 1 minute

//Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
$(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
$(this).keypress(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
})
function timerIncrement() {
idleTime = idleTime + 1;
if (idleTime > 29) { // 30 minutes
    $(selector).load(url); // or perform ajax request
}
}
</script>
```